An infinite nested radical
Can anyone help me in finding a closed form of the infinite nested radical here
$$\left({\sqrt {4+\sqrt {4+\sqrt {4-\sqrt {4+\sqrt {4+\sqrt {4- ......\infty}}}}}}}\right)$$
The signs are as "+,+,-,+,+,-" and so on
I tried using some trigonometric substitution but it didn't work out well. Can it be solved using some crazy trigonometric substitution. Does it have a closed form? Any hint or approach can be really helpful. Thanks!

Call the answer $x$, then $x=\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4-x}}}$.

@Steen82 that would give birth to an eight degree polynomial equation

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x+%3D+sqrt%284%2Bsqrt%284%2Bsqrt%284-x%29%29%29 Wolfram Alpha can solve it

@RiemanTieman https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%3D%5Csqrt%7B4%2B%5Csqrt%7B4%2B%5Csqrt%7B4-x%7D%7D%7D%24&p=1

@Steen82 would need to prove that the expression converges to some answer first

@ράτ seems to have made it work. My graphing device gives me 8 real root. Also, if this is an analysis question convergence needs to be established.

Let
$$x={\sqrt {4+\sqrt {4+\sqrt {4-\sqrt {4+\sqrt {4+\sqrt {4- ......}}}}}}}$$ then
$x={\sqrt {4+\sqrt {4+\sqrt {4-x}}}}$  Now we just need to solve for $x$
Start by eliminating the square root of the RHS
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{-x+4}+4}=x^2-4 \implies \sqrt{-x+4}+4=(x^2-4)^2 \implies-x+4=((x^2-4)^2-4)^2$$
We can expand this and move everything to one side and we get
$$-x^8+16x^6-88x^4+192x^2-x-140=0$$
This can be factored to
$$-(x^2+x-4)(x^3-2x^2-3x+5)(x^3+x^2-6x-7)=0$$
So $x^2+x-4=0$ or $x^3-2x^2-3x+5=0$ or $x^3+x^2-6x-7=0$
For $x^2+x-4=0 $ using the quadratic formula we get $ x=\frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{2}$ or $x=\frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{2}$
For $x^3-2x^2-3x+5=0 $ we can solve by substituting $y=x-\frac{2}{3}$ , write it as $5-3(y+\frac{2}{3})-2(y+\frac{2}{3})^2+(y+\frac{2}{3})^3=0$  expanding those terms we get
$$x^3-\frac{13x}{3}+\frac{65}{27}=0$$ Then we can make the beautiful substitution $y=t+\frac{λ}{κ}$ and get
$$\frac{65}{27}-\frac{13}{3}(t+\frac{λ}{κ})+(t+\frac{λ}{κ})^3=0$$
Multiply both sides by $t^3$
$$t^6+t^4(3λ-\frac{13}{2})+\frac{65 t^2}{27}+t^2(3λ^2-\frac{13λ}{3})+lλ^3=0$$
We can now substitute $λ=\frac{13}{9}$ since this value makes the coefficients of $t^2$ and $t^4$ both zero. And then Substitute $z=t^3$ making it a quadratic equation in the variable $z$
$$z^2+ \frac{65z}{27}+\frac{2197}{729}=0$$
So $z=\frac{13}{54}i(5i+3\sqrt{3}) \implies t^3=\frac{13}{54}i(5i+3\sqrt{3}) \implies $
$$x=\frac{13^{2/3}}{3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}i(3\sqrt{3}+5i}}+\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{\frac{13i}{2}(5i+3\sqrt{3})}$$
or
$$x=\frac{(-13)^{2/3}}{3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}i(3\sqrt{3}+5i}}-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-13}{2}} \sqrt[3]{(5i+3\sqrt{3}
)}$$
or
$$x=\
\frac{1}{3}(-1)^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{\frac{13i}{2}(5i+3\sqrt{3})}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{-2}13^{2/3}}{3\sqrt[3]{i(3\sqrt{3}+5i)}}$$
And for $x^3+x^2-6x-7$ We can substitute $y=x+\frac{1}{3}$ to eliminate the quadratic term
$$-7-6(y-\frac{1}{3})+(y-\frac{1}{3})^2+(y-\frac{1}{3})^3=0$$
We expand
$$y^3-\frac{19y}{3}-\frac{133}{27}=0$$ We substitute $y=t+\frac{λ}{κ}$
$$-\frac{133}{27}-\frac{19}{3}(t+\frac{λ}{κ})+(t+\frac{λ}{κ})^3=0$$
Multiply both sides by $t^3$
$$t^6+t^4(3λ-\frac{19}{3})-\frac{133 t^3}{27}+t^2(3λ^2-\frac{19λ}{3})+λ^3=0$$
Then substitute $λ=\frac{19}{9}$ and $z=t^3$ we get
$$z^2-\frac{133z}{27}+\frac{6859}{729}=0$$
And we can easily find that $$z=\frac{19}{54}(7+3i\sqrt{3}) \implies t^3=\frac{19}{54}(7+3i\sqrt{3})$$
Finally we get
$$x=-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{19^{2/3}}{3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}(3i\sqrt{3}+7)}}+\frac{1}{3} \sqrt[3]\frac{19(3i\sqrt{3}+7)}{2}$$
or
$$x=-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{(-19)^{2/3}}{3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}(3i\sqrt{3}+7)}}-\frac{1}{3} \sqrt[3]\frac{19(3i\sqrt{3}+7)}{2}$$
or
$$x=-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{(-2)^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{19}(3i\sqrt{3}+7)^{2/3}-2\sqrt[3]{-2}19^{2/3}}{6\sqrt[3]{3i\sqrt{3}+7}}$$
And at the end we need to check if those solutions satisfy the original equation.
Long story short the only solution is
$$x=-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{19^{2/3}
}{3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}(3i\sqrt{3}+7)}}+\
\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{\frac{19(3i\sqrt{3}+7)}{2}}$$
Ans so we have :
$${\sqrt {4+\sqrt {4+\sqrt {4-\sqrt {4+\sqrt {4+\sqrt {4- ......}}}}}}}=x=-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{19^{2/3}
}{3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}(3i\sqrt{3}+7)}}+\
\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{\frac{19(3i\sqrt{3}+7)}{2}} \approx 2.507$$
